# How to get biggest for specific letter and number combination (M9 for example) in lookup table EXCEL

Tags: excel

I'm currently doing a climbing performance registry. My goal is to get the max grade climbed from a lookup table (example 5.10a). This table is being modified by slicers and this is where I can't find a solution.

Example: when no slicers activated: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbYgB.png
I get the right answer 5.10a

Example2: With certain type of climb slicer activated i get #N/A: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIRVW.png

The formula I used : =INDEX(A25:A200,MATCH("Hiver",A25:A200,0)-1,1)

It is reliant on a specific word that must be under it for the function to work. I'm looking for a function that can search the table and give me the biggest grade (number and letter combination) for a specific type.

Example with no slicers : Été -> max grade is 5.10a ; glace is WI6 ; Mixte is M9.

Is this possible? Thanks :)

Comment: Refer the lookup value in match to a cell with data validation using vlookup() and choose the slice ete, hiver or none as needed.

Comment: I'll try it thanks!